# How to provide assembly version to use in TeamCity build step

Tags: teamcity

I need to add the assembly version number to the name of the artifact that TeamCity builds.

My plan is to rename the artifact after build but how do i access the assembly version in a buildstep?

Is there a standard TC parameter already available? If not then how do i send the information from my MSBuild to TC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently just done this myself and this is how I managed to do it.

If you are building a project (*.csproj) then you can, edit the csproj (In Notepad).
Add the following in the "AfterBuild" Target

***Note: Make sure it is not in a comment out block, which it is by default***

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="bin\MyAssembly.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="MyAssembly"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Message Text="Setting build number back to TeamCity... " Importance="high"/>
    <TeamCitySetBuildNumber BuildNumber="$(MyAssembly.Version)" />
</Target>
```

If you are building your Solution instead, then create an MSBUILD .proj file that you build from TeamCity, which calls to build your Solution first, then sets the Version as the BuildNumber in TeamCity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="SetBuildNumber" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Build task called... " Importance="high"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(teamcity_build_checkoutDir)\MySolution.sln" ToolsVersion="12.0" Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=bin;"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="SetBuildNumber" DependsOnTargets="Build">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="bin\MyAssembly.dll">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="MyAssembly"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Message Text="Setting build number back to TeamCity... " Importance="high"/>
    <TeamCitySetBuildNumber BuildNumber="$(MyAssembly.Version)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

With the above example, put this in a file such as MySolution.proj. Tell TeamCity to use MSBuild Runner and Build MySolution.proj and leave the Targets Blank (Which will use the defaults set in the proj file), which will run SetBuildNumber target, which in turn has a target dependency on Build, so Build will be called first. This will build your solution specified in the "Build" Target using the specified parameters, then this will run through "SetBuildNumber" which will take the AssemblyVersion of the specified dll, and send a message back to TeamCity to update the BuildNumber (%build.number%) variable.

Hope this helps.